# CF based on "Same Value" in column

Tags: excel

I need to highlight rows that contain the same value in column A. Previous threads have been helpful, but I can't find how to format for "Same value". I'm currently using:

```
=INDIRECT("a"&ROW())=280789
```

but instead of manually creating rules for each value type, I'm hoping to find a rule to do this for me.

Comment: Highlight the whole row or just the cell containing the duplicate value?

Comment: The whole row .

Answer (score 0):

- Select column `A` (as that's the column used in your code).
- On the **Home** ribbon select `Conditional Formatting`.
- Select `New Rule` from the drop-down menu.
- Select `Format only unique or duplicate values`.
- Select *duplicate* from the drop-down box and format cell to suit.
- Click "OK".

Comment: The problem with this approach is all of the values in Column A are duplicates - so everything gets highlighted the same way. 

This is a sheet documenting open projects. Each project has a project identifier in Column A - and each project has five tasks. I'm hoping to auto-highlight every other project to visually differentiate between projects.

Comment: You should edit that into your question.  Maybe have a separate sheet listing the project ID and associated colour and use that as a lookup.